# picture won't save with paperclip, rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip

I'm trying to allow a user to upload a picture.

I've read through many of the same questions here and watched several tutorials...I'm still missing something. I see image file parameters are picked up in the console, but are not saved.

Another question, why does rails want the method to be a patch instead of a post?

Thanks for your help.

Here is my model Picture:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :picture, styles: { medium: "300x300", thumb: "100x100#" }

    validates_attachment_content_type :picture, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"]

    belongs_to :user
end
```

Here is my controller:

```
def upload_image
    User.find(session[:user_id]).pictures.create(pic_params)
    redirect_to :back
end

private
def pic_params
    params.require(:upload).permit(:picture)
end
```

And here is my view page:

```
    <%= form_for(@user, :html => {:multipart => true}, :url => { :action => 'upload_image', :user_ud => @user.id }) do |f| %>
        <%= f.file_field "upload[picture]" %>
        <%= f.submit :Upload %>
    <% end %>
```

From the console:

> Started PATCH "/MeetSomeone/upload_image?user_ud=11" for ::1 at
>   2015-12-24 01:22:38 -0800 Processing by UsersController#upload_image
>   as HTML   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",
>   "authenticity_token"=>"/Fhkg2t1vivVlIisE5J5ndRO63PpOELhEwKCLfEELEWvb1XNUvV8HD5VFTnMswCGp+7v8W/wqiuQtOd4GGw2oA==",
>   "user"=>{"upload"=>{"picture"=>#,
>   @original_filename="scott.jpeg", @content_type="image/jpeg",
>   @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data;
>   name=\"user[upload[picture]]\";
>   filename=\"scott.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}},
>   "commit"=>"Upload", "user_ud"=>"11"}   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT 
>   "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 11]]
>   Completed 400 Bad Request in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
>
> ActionController::ParameterMissing (param is missing or the value is
>   empty: upload):   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:52:in
>   `pic_params'   app/controllers/users_controller.rb:46:in`
>   upload_image'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
def pic_params
   params.require(:user).permit(upload: [:picture])
end
```

The problem you have currently is that you're params hash is expecting...

```
"upload" => {
   "picture => "..."
}
```

Because you're using `form_for @user`, it's building the params hash as...

```
"user" => {
  "upload" => {
     "picture" => {
       ....
     }
  }
}
```

This is why you're getting the error:

> param is missing or the value is empty: `upload`

Your structure is really bad (I've corrected some of it below); you'd do well to read up on the [params class](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html) to see how it works.

---

I would personally do the following:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :pictures #-> url.com/pictures/new

#app/controllers/pictures_controller.rb
class PicturesController < ApplicationController
   before_action :user

   def new
     @picture = @user.pictures.new
   end

   def create
     @picture = @user.pictures.new pic_params
     @picture.save
   end

   private

   def pic_params
      params.require(:picture).permit(:image)
   end

   def user
      @user = User.find params[:session_id]
   end
end

#app/views/pictures/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @picture, multipart: true do |f| %>
   <%= f.file_field :picture %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will be accessible at `url.com/pictures/new`

I know it's not adherent to the structure of your application; I'll explain how you'd get it working with your app in a second.

The important thing to note about Rails is its *object orientated* nature; every time you create a record, it's actually an *object*. The problem you have is that you're getting confused with which object you're trying to create, leading your params hash to be incorrect.

By using a *pictures* controller (rather than adding to the `users` controller), you are able to create a `Picture` object on the back of the user association. The way you're doing it currently would require you to use `accepts_nested_attributes_for`, which can get tricky:

---

The way you *should* be doing what you're doing is to use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) - which basically means that you're able to send nested data to an associated model.

Since you wish to use your `users` controller, it would be better for you to send the `picture` object as nested --

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :users do
   match :upload_image, via: [:get, :patch], on: :collection #-> url.com/users/upload_image #-> you're using session[:user_id] so no need for member route
end

#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :picture
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :picture
end

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
   before_action :set_user

   def upload_image
      if request.get?
         @user.build_picture unless @user.picture
      elsif request.patch?
         @user.update pic_params
         redirect_to @user
      end
   end

   private

   def pic_params
      params.require(:user).permit(picture_attributes: [:picture])
   end

   def set_user
      @user = User.find params[:user_id] #-> this is 
   end
end
```

This will allow you to use:

```
#app/views/users/upload_image.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.fields_for :picture do |p| %>
      <%= p.file_field :picture %>
   <% end %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

Finally, a pro-tip I give out is the [`paperclip_defaults`](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#defaults) option for Paperclip:

```
#config/application.rb
...
config.paperclip_defaults = {
   styles: { medium: "300x300", thumb: "100x100#" }
}
```

This will set the default options for any `Paperclip` enabled model you have (which can be overridden of course).

Ultimately, it means that you're able to clean up your models quite simply:

```
#app/models/picture.rb
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

    has_attached_file :picture
    validates :picture, content_type: { content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"] }
end
```